# Use a regex to find a pattern somewhere between two words

Tags: java, regex

Given the following string

```
{"type":"PrimaryParty","name":"Karen","id":"456789-9996"},
{"type":"SecondaryParty","name":"Juliane","id":"345678-9996"},
{"type":"SecondaryParty","name":"Ellen","id":"001234-9996"}
```

I am looking for strings matching the pattern \d{6}-\d{4}, but only if they are following the string "SecondaryParty". The processor is Java-based

Using https://regex101.com/ I have come up with this, which works fine using the ECMAScript(JavaScript) Flavor.

`(?<=SecondaryParty.*?)\d{6}-\d{4}(?=\"})`

But as soon as I switch to Java, it says

```
* A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width
? The preceding token is not quantifiable
```

When using it in java.util.regex, the error says

`Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 20 (?<=SecondaryParty.*?)\d{6}-\d{4}(?="}) ^`

How do I overcome the "does not have an obvious maximum length" problem in Java?

Comment: Have you contemplated doing it in multipasses? Regex is not always the best tool. Even if it's possible, you'll likely loose a lot of CPU cycles compared to actually parsing it as JSON and then do your job on that.

Comment: Remove `?` in `.*?`

Comment: @TedLyngmo No I am not considering using other than Regex for this. I am utilizing a generic Regex-service in our service infrastructure.

Comment: @Unmitigated That didn't do the trick, it still triggers the "obvious maximum length" error. But I found a solution. I can replace the `.*` with a static range like `.{0,200}`. This simulates a wildcard of 0 to 200 characters. So the regex looks like this `(?<=SecondaryParty.{0,200})\d{6}-\d{4}(?=\"})`

Comment: That data very much looks like a [JSON](https://www.json.org/), have you considered using a JSON parser?

Comment: @JörgAsmussen Doesn't your service infra structure contain an actual JSON parser too?

Comment: We have a module something like a JSON-mapper, but the data in question here requires the recognition of a X-Path-ish parser, which can relate sibling-data. in the above example, as the id of "PrimaryParty" must be excluded. 

Our system is a modular i/o data processor, where we have precoded modules, that have integration flow definitions, where we essentially do some sort of ETL. One of the modules is a Regex-processor, for which I needed a generic regex to select e.g. 2 out of 3 ID's. The beautiful part is, that one "simple" regex is able to do just that.

Comment: Just FYI, here is the module code, processing the request. As said, I am not able to change this code and to implement group-fetchning, as suggested below.  

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`  
`Matcher m = p.matcher(sourceText);`  
`while (m.find()) {`  
`    String value = m.group();`  
`    arrayBuilder.add(value);`  
`}`  
`return arrayBuilder.build();`

(Editing code in comments ain't easy, is it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a curly braces quantifier as a workaround:

```
(?<=SecondaryParty.{0,255})\d{6}-\d{4}(?=\"})
```

The minimum and maximum inside curly braces quantifier are depend on your actual data.

Comment: Thanks Trung, this was the solution I found, too. I will have to put a fixed max which allows for the maximum name length of the source system.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value without using lookarounds by matching instead, and use a single capture group for the value that you want to get:

```
\"SecondaryParty\"[^{}]*\"(\d{6}-\d{4})\"
```

**Explanation**

- `\"SecondaryParty\"` Match `"SecondaryParty"`
- `[^{}]*\"` Match optional chars other than `{` and `}`
- `(\d{6}-\d{4})` Capture **group 1**, match 6 digits `-` 4 digits
- `\"` Match `"`

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ndWRaU/1) and a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/IgjqWF).

Comment: Brilliant! Do you see any problem with [this simplification](https://regex101.com/r/3S8lY6/1)?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash That would also work, I did not use `.*` but `[^{}]*` because of the example strings to not cross the curly's

Comment: Thank you both, but as I wrote to @josephjacobmorris answer, using groups will require a change to the running java code, which is out of the question at this time.

Comment: Is it possible to create a regex with groups, and have a specific group returned in standard, possibly by assigning \1 as the group returned?

Comment: @JörgAsmussen I don't think you can do that, you can pick the group 1 value from the code, but the full match will still be what the whole pattern matched. In that case you can use the lookbehind assertion from the other pattern, and maybe make it a bit more specific matching the quotes and prevent matching the curly's in between `(?<=\"SecondaryParty\"[^{}]{0,255})\d{6}-\d{4}(?=\"})` https://regex101.com/r/q6Hyyw/1

Answer (score 0):

You could use `(?<=SecondaryParty)(.*?)(\d{6}-\d{4})(?=\"})` regex expression and take the value of the second group which will match the pattern \d{6}-\d{4}, but only if they are following the string "SecondaryParty".

Sample Java code

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class IdRegexMatcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input ="{\"type\":\"PrimaryParty\",\"name\":\"Karen\",\"id\":\"456789-9996\"},\n" +
                "{\"type\":\"SecondaryParty\",\"name\":\"Juliane\",\"id\":\"345678-9996\"},\n" +
                "{\"type\":\"SecondaryParty\",\"name\":\"Ellen\",\"id\":\"001234-9996\"}";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=SecondaryParty)(.*?)(\\d{6}-\\d{4})(?=\\\"})");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String idStr = matcher.group(2);
            System.out.println(idStr);
        }
    }
}
```

which gives the output 
345678-9996
001234-9996

One possible optimization in the above regex could be to use [^0-9]*? instead of .*? under the assumption that the name wouldn't contain numbers.

Comment: I thought about that, but the java code in question is not modifiable, as it comprises a working service within our infrastructure. I have to rely on a solution comprising of modifying the regular expression only. I am sorry I was not expressing that clearly.